# webpack-dev-server fails to run with error of validateSchema

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

this is a react hello-world proj , on local machine win7, use npm download 
packages, when run " webpack-dev-server --open " it has an error like these:

```html
F:\now\react\setup\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:7
const validateSchema = process.webpackModule.validateSchema;

TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateSchema' of undefined
...
```

[screenshot about error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXFe.jpg)

this is the package.json and webpack.config.js

```html
{
  "name": "setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```html
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./src",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
  },
   
  module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            "env", "react"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use yarn (it usally fixes issues like this on its own) and delete your node_modules folder and reinstall everything. It seems some dependency you are using is deprecated or not updated for the webpack version you are using. Make sure everything is updated. Is your NodeJS updated? Also, use create-react-app as your boilerplate (if you haven't already), you can always customize it via eject later on.

Comment: @Prometheus ths! is yarn easier to learn than npm ?

Comment: NPM and Yarn are both package managers, which means besides a few commands you don't really have to 'learn' anything. They are simply there to manage and install packages you want to use. See [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpack-cli just bumped from v2 to v3 about 10 hours ago, and it looks like this might be a bug with v3. I haven't figured out an actual fix yet, but a temporary workaround is to downgrade to webpack-cli v2 by manually changing the version number in your `package.json` to `^2.0.0`.

Hope that helps you get unstuck for the moment.